# Swift autolayout: update view's dimension

Tags: swift, autolayout, pure-layout

I'm using [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)

I'm doing all the layout by code, by the way.

I have a `UIScrollView` that functions like Facebook's news feed. My scroll view has some subviews. Let's call 'em **"cards"**.

I've set my constraints inside `updateConstraints` as such:

```
for (i, view) in enumerate(self.viewsForAutoLayout) {
    /** Set view dimension **/
    view.autoSetDimension(ALDimension.Width,  toSize: view.frame.width)
    view.autoSetDimension(ALDimension.Height, toSize: view.frame.height)

    /** Make 'em stack **/
    if i == 0 {
        view.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(
            ALEdge.Top,
            withInset: offset
        )
    } else {
        view.autoPinEdge(
            ALEdge.Top,
            toEdge: ALEdge.Bottom,
            ofView: self.viewsForAutoLayout[i - 1],
            withOffset: offset
        )
    }
}

self.setNeedsLayout()
```

And in `layoutSubviews`, this is where I resize the **cards**. Their respective height is being updated after an image is loaded from the internet (via `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest`, fyi, but not related to this topic.) After that, I update my `scrollView`'s height.

```
for (i, view) in enumerate(self.viewsForAutoLayout) {
    view.realignContent()
}

totalHeight += view.frame.size.height + offset

let size = CGSizeMake(AppConstants.ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, totalHeight)
self.scrollView.resizeContent(size) // extension
```

**The problem is that they're not being aligned properly.** It's like calling `setNeedsLayout()` (which eventually calls `layoutSubviews()` -- correct me if I've mistaken) that does not align the content at all. I've also made sure that `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` is called as well.

I've tried calling this in `layoutSubviews`...

```
view.autoSetDimension(ALDimension.Height, toSize: view.frame.height)
```

...but I get some kind of warning:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand,
refer to the documentation for the UIView property  
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700918a0 V:[XXX.ContentBox:0x15fd63a80(928.986)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098bf0 V:[XXX.ContentBox:0x15fd63a80(1275.99)]>"
)
```

*(`ContentBox` is my `UIView` for the card)*

**The cards look messed up.** What should I do to align my cards properly?

*I'd gladly answer side comments regarding the code if it helps understand the question. :) Suggestions on the side aren't bad either.*

Answer (score 0):

Going by the warning you're seeing, it looks like you need to set  `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` when you instantiate your *card* view.

Comment: I added it and it doesn't change the effect :(